# Distinct elements based off roots of unity

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

I'm working on a problem, but I haven't been able to get much out of it...

Given that $\zeta$ is a *primitive* complex n-th root of unity, show that the complex numbers $1,\zeta,\zeta^2,...,\zeta^{n-1}$ are all distinct, meaning that no two of them are equal. Note that it is not specified *which* primitive n-th root $\zeta$ is.

I believe I have to incorporate the orders of these $\zeta$ elements in some way. From what I know, a primitive complex n-th root of unity is when $O(\zeta) = n$, where $O(\zeta)$ is the order of $\zeta$. With this in mind, how would I show each of the elements,  $1,\zeta,\zeta^2,...,\zeta^{n-1}$ are all distinct..?

Comment: To show $1,\zeta,\zeta^2,...,\zeta^{n-1}$ are all distinct, suppose
$$\zeta^a = \zeta^b$$
where $0 \le a < b \le n-1$.
Divide both sides by $\zeta^a$, and a contradiction should be apparent.

Comment: Can you explain what the contradiction is?

Comment: So $1 = \zeta^{b-a}$?

Comment: Right, and $0 < b-a < n$, so therefore ...

Comment: $1 \neq \zeta^n$?

Comment: No, that's not the contradiction. The contradiction is that by definition of primitive $n$-th root of unity, the least positive integer $m$ such that $\zeta^m = 1$ is $m = n$.

Comment: Ah now I see it. So $b-a \neq n$ in this case then.

Comment: The key is that $b-a$ is a positive integer _less_ than $n$. If $b-a = 2n$, say, there would be no contradiction.

Comment: By the way, you still didn't edit the question. You need the list to end at $\zeta^{n-1}$, not $\zeta^n$.

Comment: This makes sense now. We just began talking about primitive roots of unity in my class, but haven't had much exposure to applying it to verify certain results.

Comment: Ah yes that's a typo... will fix now.

Comment: There's still one more occurrence of that same typo.

Comment: Should be good to go.

Comment: Yes, all fixed.